# Find image from a database of images

Tags: python, opencv, flann

I'm moving my first steps with OpenCV in Python.
What I'd wish to do is given an image, find its "original" one from a collection of reference images. Just to be clear, the query image is a simple photo of the whole image (card), so it's not the scenario "find an object inside a photo", but "just" a similarity test.
My final database will be pretty large (about 25 000 images), but I started doing some tests on a smaller scale (only 270 images).
Recognition works perfectly, however it's pretty slow: it takes 8 seconds to iterate over all 270 images. I was able to speed up the job by saving the descriptors to disk and load them, instead of calculating them; anyway it's still slow.

So I started to work on FLANN: I get some results, but my main problem is to find the matching images. I get a whole array of points, but I don't know how to fetch the right image.
This is my code:

```
scanned = 'tests/temp_bw.png'
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(400)
surf.setUpright(True)

img1 = cv2.imread(scanned, 0)
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1, None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)

des_all = None
for filename in os.listdir('images'):
    img2 = cv2.imread('images/' + filename, 0)
    kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
    if des_all is None:
        des_all = des2
    else:
        des_all = np.concatenate((des_all, des2))

flann = cv2.flann.Index()
print "Training..."
flann.build(des_all, index_params)
print "Matching..."
indexes, matches = flann.knnSearch(des1, 10)
# and now???
```

Any suggestions on how I can reference back the most similar image?

**EDIT**
This is the shape of `des2`

```
print des2.shape
(1731, 64)
(2144, 64)
(1811, 64)
(1649, 64)
```

These are the return values from `flann.knnSearch`:

```
pprint(matches[0])
array([ 0.0463759], dtype=float32)

pprint(indexes[0])
array([249106], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. Your initial approach used some similarity-calculation and you did use linear-search to find the maximum. Now, using approximate-search, you will get 10 candidates. Just do the same over these 10 (probably using indexes to be able to retrieve your data to compare; but that's depending on flann -> docs); or just ask for 1 candidate in the first-place, or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While building your des_all, make a list that has the same length as the number of descriptors, where each element is the index of the image this descriptor is from.

Once you have your matched features, you can look this up in the list, which image the feature was matched in. Then you can do a simple majority vote on which image is correct, or use the inverse of the distances to weigh the votes by importance.

---

Edit: If you modify your for loop like this, you can build the list that has the number of which image has generated which features:

```
for index, filename in enumerate(os.listdir('images')):
    img2 = cv2.imread('images/' + filename, 0)
    kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
    indexList.extend([index]*des2.shape[0])
```

If you do the voting by majority voting, it can be done like this (each feature votes for the image it's matched to, and the image with the most votes wins)

```
votes = indexList[indexes]
from collections import Counter
votes = Counter()
likelyMatch = votes.most_common()[0][0]
```

If you want to weigh using the distance of the matches, you should remember that the distances in `matches` are squared, and you should take the square root. These distances can be used as inverse weights, to make each feature vote with higher or lower weight, depending on how good of a match it is.

Comment: I *think* I got what you're saying, but I'm missing some bits. Do you mind to share some code? Regarding the "weight by distance": I think I can't use that since `indexes` nor `matches` have any distance info (but maybe I used the wrong method)

Comment: Could you tell me the size of `des2`, I can try adding some code to the answer.  `matches` should be the squared euclidean distance between the two descriptors.

Comment: I updated the question with some info on the variables and returned values

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked very well! I had to do a few changes but the whole logic is correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A simple (and very old, at least 1980s) technique is to calculate a spatial hash from each image, then match the hashes. For example:

http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/?/archives/529-Kind-of-Like-That.html

You can find an exact match very quickly.

Finding an approximate match is a little harder: you'd need to store low-res hashes, match those, then calculate the hamming distance for the larger hashes.

There are lots of implementations around, for example `dhash` is a Ruby gem based on ImageMagick:

https://github.com/maccman/dhash

You can also compare histograms. They have the advantage of being invariant under rotate.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the query image is taken from the camera, while the test database has the high quality scanned ones, so I can't do an exact match. Regarding `dhash`, I suspect I'll get the same problem again: I have to iterate over all files one by one

Comment: Things like dhash work surprisingly well. It's certainly worth trying.

Comment: @tampe125, here is slightly another algorithm and I've provided 4 links to read about improving Hamming distance neighbors search: https://github.com/Nakilon/dhash-vips